# TypeScript: letting users of a library define types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's say I have a simple state management library that looks like:

```
var appState;

export const createState = (obj) => {
  appState = obj;
}

export const getStore = (store) => {
  return appState[store];
}
```

In TypeScript, I'd like users of the library to be able to define their state types, eg:

```
interface DrawerState {
  open: boolean
}

interface ModalState {
  open: boolean,
  title: string
}

interface AppState {
  drawer: DrawerState;
  modal: ModalState;
}
```

And for TS to be able to determine the return type of `getState` based on the string passed in (which we assume can be statically determined).

```
const appState: AppState = {
  drawer: {open: false},
  modal: {open: false, title: 'the modal'}
};

const store = createStore(appState)

// I want TS to "know" that drawerState is of type DrawerState here!
const drawerState = getState('drawer');
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're looking for a typescript feature called "generics"

```
export function createState<State>(state: State): State {
 //                          ↑             ↑       ↑
 //                   (generic type)    (usage of generic)

  return state
}

interface MyState {
  a: boolean
  b: number
}

const state = createState<MyState>({a: true, b: 1})
 //                        ↑
 //             (specify which type to use)

// the argument must conform to MyState,
// and the return value is of type MyState
```

Comment: Right, thank you, but ultimately I'd like to define my private `appState` variable to be a generic type... not sure if that is possible.

Comment: This problem arose when I converted a JS lib I created to TS:  https://github.com/kmurph73/set-state-is-great.  

Basically, I'd like to be able to define my state's structure in TS, and have `getState` and `setState` "know" the returning type.  Perhaps this requires reworking the API though.

Comment: @kmurph79 "my private appState" — you need to think of this problem differently — if `appState` is private (not publicly accessible) then you don't need to relate it to a public type — if the consumer needs `appState` to have their correct type, it means they are interacting with it directly, which is not allowed for private things

Comment: @kmurph79 — also, it's always a bad pattern to use module-level state (like your appState), so instead, define a class which takes the generic type, and make `appState` a private member of that class — `class StateDealer<State> { private appState: State; }` — avoiding global/module-level variables will improve your architecture and make this thing encapsulated, isolatable, testable

Comment: Cool, thanks, will try reworking the internals a bit as you suggest.